# ¿Como puedo referenciar un archivo de mi proyecto de Visual Studio para generar los archivos y carpetas iniciales que necesita mi programa?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, deployment

el motivo de la consulta es el siguiente, hace no mucho escribi una pregunta, porque no me funciona el programa al empaquetar, tras las respuestas vi que el problema principalmente era mi forma de acceder a ciertos archivos que son necesarios para el programa, especialmente archivos de credenciales etc.

Para solucionar esto, voy a usar `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`

Que me indica la dirección donde esta el ejecutable, y entonces creo las carpetas del programa, imagenes, logs, etc.

El problema lo tengo con los archivos, ya que la idea es que al ejecutar el programa, si no existe por ejemplo credentials2.txt, lo cree, pero claro pongamos un ejemplo:

Programa.exe (programa ya empaquetado) necesita generar credentials2.txt, usando como base el archivo credentials.txt (el original, que el programa necesita y debería estar empaquetado en programa.exe).

¿como hago yo referencia a ese archivo ya empaquetado (credentials.txt)? es decir el archivo que debería estar contenido en programa.exe, para luego hacer un simple copy del archivo e ir generando uno por uno todos los archivos esenciales y así asegurarme que si o si estaran todos los archivos esenciales.

**Editado:** indico aquí a que me refiero por empaquetar, me refiero a cuando le das a publicar y entre las opciones indicas que te genere un solo archivo ejecutable un .exe, dentro de ese exe estan el resto de archivos, lo que quiero es que cuando ejecutas el exe, este mire en su interior esos archivos busque por ejemplo el archivo credenciales, y lo genere en la carpeta utils, así tendre los archivos fácilmente localizables y sabre seguro que se generaron correctamente.

Comment: A que te refieres con "empaquetado"? Hay diferententes formas de adjuntar un archivo (de texto en este caso) en tu aplicacion

Comment: esta muy enredada la pregunta, no te hace falta reflection para recorrer el directorio y buscar un archivo, la libreria system.io tiene las clases necesarias para saber si un archivo existe. Tambien podes agregar un archivo a tu proyecto, abrir, recorrerlo y copiar lo necesario.

Comment: Debes tener en cuenta que una vez empaquetado tu archivo.exe no puedes modificarlo, si deseas crear otro archivo debes hacerlo afuera, en otra dirección o en la misma carpeta si deseas pero no colocarlo dentro de un assembly o en tu ejecutable.

Comment: Por empaquetado me refiero, a cuando en visual studio se utiliza la opción de publicar, y le indicas que genere 1 solo archivo final de salida, un .exe en el que incluye todos los demás archivos, yo lo que quiero es que al pulsar sobre ese exe final busque internamente el archivo de credenciales por ejemplo y genere el archivo externo en por ejemplo Utils. Así sabre donde localizarlo y seguro que se han generado todos los archivos que necesita la aplicación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si alguien más tiene un problema similar, ya he encontrado como hacerlo, en el build action del archivo que necesito hay que marcar como contenido (content) y en copiar en el directorio de salida (Copy to Output) como Copiar si es posterior(Copy if newer).

Eso genera el archivo en la salida con la misma carpeta etc, que tiene en el proyecto.